# How to Data Engineer a dataset to get the best featurres to predict a target class?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering, feature-extraction, accuracy, data-engineering

In my dataset, I have data of IDs that don't create any meaningful relationship with each other and when I test that dataset on different models I am not getting accuracy more than 40%.

[image]

Anyone can assist me to map or data engineer my features to build a meaningful relation in data to get my desired accuracy.

In my dataset assign_to is the target and machine and location id's are features.

Answer (score 0):

You can't used IDs to do machine learning. IDs are not dependent variables and they are not independent variables.

Comment: I understand this thing, that's the main cause of low accuracy. 
Can we use IDs by mapping them into meaningful values?